# PHP Extension for C is failing to find function in C Library

Tags: php, c, linux, php-extension

**Problem**

I am learning to create a php extension.  I have created a php extension for a basic hello world app.  But the moment I try to include functions from the C library I am trying to entend then I get the following error message:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/hello.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/hello.so: undefined symbol: nc_open in Unknown on line 0

This nc_open() function is the key function in the libary I am trying to extend

**Process**

I have created by header and config files and my c extension file which contains:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include "php.h"
#include "php_hello.h"
#include <netcdf.h>
```

...

```
PHP_FUNCTION(hello_world)
{
    int status;
    int ncid;
    status = nc_open("sample.nc", 0, &ncid);
    RETURN_LONG(status);
}
```

I have set up a directory (on Ubuntu) and run the phpize and configure steps.  I run the make command which runs with no errors.

In my php.ini file I have the hello.so extension which points to symbolic link to the file I make.

I then restart the apache server on my local machine and then run:

php -r 'echo hello_world();'

and get:
- /usr/lib/php5/20121212/hello.so: undefined symbol: nc_open in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function hello_world() in Command line code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() Command line code:0

The error only occurs when I have a function from netcdf.h
The error does not occur from just having the include statement.

**What I've tried:**

Firstly I tried writing a basic c program to check that it would work, I managed to succeed by compiling it with:

gcc test.c -lnetcdf -o Test
and running ./Test

I tried using the following MakeFile

LDLIBS = -lnetcdf

but was unsuccessful.

**What I would like:**

Preferably to know how to get this library to work in my extension but I would settle for being pointed to documents or examples to help me understand what I need to know to accomplish this.

**Update**

Following Elliott Frisch's comments I have tried the 
Setting the PHP_RPATHS=/usr/local

Setting /etc/ld.so.conf to:

> include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
>
> /usr/lib

Changing the MakeFile to:

> LDLIBS = -lnetcdf
>
> LDFLAGS = -static

I am making the assumption that /usr/local is the correct directory due to it containing netcdf.so

I have added the following lines to my config.m4 file according to try adding the suggested functions

```
PHP_ADD_INCLUDE(/usr/lib)
PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH(netcdf, /usr/lib, HELLO_SHARED_LIBADD)
```

Unfortunately I am still getting the problem so I am trying to understand what these functions mean to make sure I using them correctly.  (The library I need to connect to is /usr/lib/libnetcdf.a and need to include netcdf.h from that file.)

Comment: I think you either recompile `php` to link the `netcdf` library, or you compile your module with a static version of your `netcdf` library .

Comment: Please show the exact commands used to compile and link your PHP extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with an incorrectly configured config.m4 file.

I added the following that I modified from examples I found to get it to work:

```
if test "$PHP_HELLO" != "no"; then
  SEARCH_PATH="/usr/local /usr"     # you might want to change this
  SEARCH_FOR="/include/netcdf.h"  # you most likely want to change this
  if test -r $PHP_HELLO/$SEARCH_FOR; then # path given as parameter
    HELLO_INC_DIR=$PHP_HELLO/include
  else # search default path list
    AC_MSG_CHECKING([for netcdf.h in default path])
    for i in $SEARCH_PATH ; do
      if test -r $i/$SEARCH_FOR; then
        HELLO_INC_DIR=$i/include
        AC_MSG_RESULT(found in $i)
      fi
    done
  fi
  if test -z "$HELLO_INC_DIR"; then
    AC_MSG_RESULT([not found])
  fi

  SEARCH_PATH="/usr/local /usr"     # you might want to change this
  SEARCH_FOR="/lib/libnetcdf.a"  # you most likely want to change this
  if test -r $PHP_HELLO/$SEARCH_FOR; then # path given as parameter
    HELLO_LIB_DIR=$PHP_HELLO/lib
  else # search default path list
    AC_MSG_CHECKING([for libnetcdf in default path])
    for i in $SEARCH_PATH ; do
      if test -r $i/$SEARCH_FOR; then
        HELLO_LIB_DIR=$i/lib
        AC_MSG_RESULT(found in $i)
      fi
    done
  fi

  if test -z "$HELLO_LIB_DIR"; then
    AC_MSG_RESULT([not found])
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Please check the netCDF distribution])
  fi
  # --with-netcdf -> add include path
  PHP_ADD_INCLUDE($HELLO_INC_DIR)

  # --with-netcdf -> check for lib and symbol presence
  LIBNAME=netcdf # you may want to change this
  dnl O_LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS
  dnl LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L$NETCDF_LIB_DIR -l$LIBNAME"
  PHP_ADD_LIBRARY($LIBNAME)
  LIBSYMBOL=nc_inq_libvers # you most likely want to change this 

  PHP_CHECK_LIBRARY($LIBNAME,$LIBSYMBOL,
  [
    PHP_ADD_LIBRARY($LIBNAME)
      AC_DEFINE(HAVE_HELLO,1,[Build netCDF extension])
  ],[
      AC_MSG_ERROR([wrong netCDF library version or lib not found])
  ])

  PHP_SUBST(HELLO_SHARED_LIBADD)
  HELLO_SHARED_LIBADD=-l$LIBNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `PHP_ADD_LIBRARY_WITH_PATH` & `PHP_ADD_INCLUDE` macros in `config.m4` to handle linking. Autoconf's macros are also helpful for find & verifying existing libraries.

The best examples can be found in the **ext** directory of PHP's source code. Like [ext/zlib](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/zlib/config0.m4#L59-L63)

```
PHP_ADD_LIBPATH($ZLIB_DIR/$PHP_LIBDIR, ZLIB_SHARED_LIBADD)
PHP_ZLIB_DIR=$ZLIB_DIR
PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(z,, ZLIB_SHARED_LIBADD)
PHP_ADD_INCLUDE($ZLIB_INCDIR)
```

And more detailed examples in [ext/oracle](http://opensource.apple.com/source/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-12/php/ext/oracle/config.m4) (from apple's open source labs)

```
PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(clntsh, 1, ORACLE_SHARED_LIBADD)
PHP_ADD_LIBPATH($ORACLE_DIR/lib, ORACLE_SHARED_LIBADD)
```